# Error when accessing database

Tags: c#, database, database-connection

I'm really new to using databases with Windows WPF applications and am getting an error message as follows -

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

I am unsure as to why this error is occurring and was wondering if anyone could help solve it?

The code I've used to try and connect to the database:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

    private void Item_List_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"F:\VS Projects\POS applicarion\POS applicarion\Imes.sdf");
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(conn.CreateCommand());
        adapt.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from item";
        adapt.Fill(dataset);
        PopulateListBox();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try doubling the backwhacks ("\") in your connection string, so that it's "F:\\VS Projects\\POS applicarion\\POS applicarion\\Imes.sdf" On second look, that's just a path; the connection string is more complex than that, something more like: "SERVER=PLATYPUS;DATABASE=DUCKBILLdata;UID=poisontoe;PWD=swamppooch;Connection Timeout=0"

Answer (score 0):

As the comment in your question, the connection string is wrong.

You must supply the `SqlConnection`'s constructor parameter with the correct syntax of SQL Server connection string.

For example:
`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;`

Please visit http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for more syntax samples of connection strings.